# Update a matrix into a text file without appending the results

Tags: matrix, file-io, fortran, fortran77

I have a Fortran 77 code like this, more or less:

```
nMaxRow=100
nMaxStep=100
! initialization of the matrix if Step=1
do step=1,nMaxStep

   if (step.eq.1) then
      do ii=1,nMaxRow
         do jj=1,nMaxStep
            A(ii,jj)=0
         end do
      end do
   end if


!now for each step and for each row update the cell of the matrix
   do ii=1,nMaxRow
      A(ii,step)=X(ii)  !X(ii) is a number associated with the specific ow at that specific step
   end do

!Now I want to write the updated matrix at this step into a text file,
!How can I do that????

end do   !close the do step...
```

Is it possible to update the values of the matrix and write the updated matrix at that specific step into a text file? I mean, without appending the results each step...

I found out that for Fortran 90 the 'REPLACE' command exists... but I couldn't find anything similar for Fortran 77.

One simple idea would be deleting the file just before writing a new one... but I don't like it and I don't know how to do it anyway.

Comment: what compiler are you using that doesn't support `STATUS='REPLACE'` ?  In any case most compilers back to f77 would do replace if you open `STATUS='UNKNOWN'`

Comment: @agentp I didn't find status REPLACE in my Fortran 77 do so I assume it is indeed F90. I have silently assumed the compiler would do the replace on reopenning in my answer.

Comment: REPLACE is f90, my point is he most likely doesnt really have a f77 compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is already open (from the previous writing), you can just go the the start of the file using

```
  rewind(unitnumber)
```

and start writing again. It will delete the original content of the file and start again. If you wan't to go back just be several records, you can use `backtrace()`, but you probably don't want that here.

If it isn't open, just open it and start writing. Unless you open it of appending, it will overwrite the original content.